# Recyclerview with Section but with a Footer only per section

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Good day all,

I have a Recyclerview, where on first load achieves the result I want which is grouping all the Trades a specific seller is selling, by that seller.

Example:

---

- Bob selling a watch.
- Bob selling a car.
- Bob selling a horse.
- Button to remove all Bobs trades

  ---
- Jim selling a house.
- Jim selling a monkey.
- Button to remove all Jims trades

  ---

ect

Example:

[image]

The issue is the minute I start scrolling the recyclerview, the rows of items get mixed up.

The way I did this was, I have a single layout that holds a Vertical Linear Layout with a green button below the LinearLayout.

Now I was programatically inflating the view for each Row, then setting the data for that row.

[image: A Row]

This is my onBindViewHolder:

```
      @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final ParentCartResultsViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final LinkedHashMap<Long, List<Trade>> mapTradesBySeller = CartUtils.getUserToFixedPriceTradeMap();
    mTradesBySeller = (new ArrayList<>(mapTradesBySeller.values())).get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

    if (mTradesBySeller != null) {
      for (Trade trade : mTradesBySeller) {
        View singleTrade = LayoutInflater.from(MyApplication.getAppContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_trade_details_include_row, holder.mLinearLayout, false);
        TextView tradeTitle = (TextView) singleTrade.findViewById(R.id.trade_details_include_trade_title);
        tradeTitle.setText(trade.getTitle());
        TextView endDate = (TextView) singleTrade.findViewById(R.id.trade_details_include_trade_ending_time);
        endDate.setText(trade.getUserAlias() + " : " + trade.getUserId());
        holder.mLinearLayout.addView(singleTrade);
      }
    }
  }
```

My onCreateViewHolder:

```
      @Override
  public ParentCartResultsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_grouped_by_seller, parent, false);
    return new ParentCartResultsViewHolder(v);
  }
```

Now I think I know what the issue is, its just I cant figure out how I can fix it.

The problem is the creating of the views and adding them to the LinearLayout is in the onBindViewHolder, as this runs numerous times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) to easily group your data into sections and add a footer to each section.

First create a Section class:

```
class TradeSection extends StatelessSection {

    List<String> list;

    public TradeSection(List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(-1, R.layout.section_item, R.layout.section_footer);

        // remove header
        this.setHasHeader(false);

        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getFooterViewHolder(View view) {
        return new MyFooterViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindFooterViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyFooterViewHolder footerHolder = (MyFooterViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your footer view here
        footerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data for each year
TradeSection section1 = new TradeSection(bobDataList);
TradeSection section2 = new TradeSection(jimDataList);

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(section1);
sectionAdapter.addSection(section2);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

Comment: Dude, THANK YOU! this sorted the issue that i have been having for over a week! Appreciate it!! :D Up voted and set as answer!